# Different contexts with InstancePerRequest using Autofac

Tags: c#, linq, dependency-injection, autofac

I am using Autofac for DI in my project (web application). I have a LINQ expression which joins 2 different tables in the same DB something like this (All() is just a wrapper over dbSet.AsQueryable())

```
from repo1 in repository1.All()
join repo2 in repository2.All()
     on repo1.SomeField = repo2.SomeField
.....
```

I am registering my components (repo1 and repo2) in the container builder with InstancePerRequest().

When I execute my code, at the LINQ code, it throws be following error:" The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts."

I thought the dbContext is shared (per request) across components registered via InstancePerRequest().

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: How is your dbContext being created?  Is it registered through autofac as well?  If so, how is it being registered?

Comment: When you say it's a web application, what type do you mean? Is this WebApi, WCF, MVC, or something else? Are you using the appropriate autofac integration library for your application type?

Comment: You do not show your "repository" constructor. If you want it to work properly, you need to register your `DbContext` with `PerRequest` as well and make your "repositories" get it injected as constructor parameter. Then it will just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not show your "repository" constructor. If you want it to work properly, you need to register your `DbContext` with `PerRequest` as well and make your "repositories" get it injected as constructor parameter. Then it will just work. There is no implicit assumption that dependencies of components registered `PerRequest` should be instantiated with the same lifecycle. By default all components are registered per dependency.

Comment: Thanks Alexey. I missed injected DbContext in my repository constructor. Working fine now.